# Mandrill or Magento adding %20 to the end of my links

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm currently using Mandrill to track my transaction emails.  Within those emails I have links.  Not sure why but when I click on the links via the preview or within my email client the links come up with errors.

Here is what comes up. "https://www.facebook.com/myshop%20" The %20 breaks the link.

Below is the original code.

```
<div class="social-links icon-wrapper-square">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/myshop "title="Facebook" target="_new">
<img src="{{media url="social/facebook-icon.png"}}">
</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Magento 1.9.2
Mandrill 2.0.7

Answer (score 5):

You have a whitespace at the end of the url:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/myshop "title="Facebook" target="_new">`

should be:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/myshop" title="Facebook" target="_new">`

`%20` is a white space, encoded for URL.